# How can I watch my contract using Ganache testRPC?

Tags: web3js, testrpc, ganache

I want to get the transaction hash + contract address ... using Ganache testRPC.
since I don't have the option of using etherscan because testrpc of ganache use everything locally.

Comment: I would also like to know this